# Google KMS asymmetric keys validation failure

Tags: node.js, typescript, digital-signature, google-cloud-kms

I'm working on an OAuth server implementation for custom purposes, and tried using Google's KMS service for the signining/verification of JWT tokens.

I was able to create a signature just fine, problems started with verification step - always resulting in false (invalid token). I then proceed to simplify the code to find the reason and ended up with a code that I wasn't able to simplify more, but still didn't work. I based the code on the examples in [Google KMS Docs](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/create-validate-signatures).

```js
export async function sign (message: string): Promise<Buffer> {
    const name = getKeyPath();
    const digest = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(message).digest();

    const [ result ] = await client.asymmetricSign({
        name,
        digest: {
            sha512: digest
        }
    });

    return result.signature as Buffer;
}

export async function verify (message: string, signature: Buffer): Promise<boolean> {
    const publicKey = await getPublicKey();
    const verifier = crypto.createVerify('SHA512');

    verifier.write(message);
    verifier.end();

    return verifier.verify(publicKey, signature);
}

export async function getPublicKey (): Promise<string> {
    const name = getKeyPath();

    const [ publicKey ] = await client.getPublicKey({ name });

    return publicKey.pem;
}

(async () => {
    const message = 'test';
    const signature = await sign(message);
    const valid = await verify(message, signature);

    console.log(message);
    console.log(signature);
    console.log(valid);
})();
```

Result:

```sh
test
<Buffer 19 a2 89 37 e5 43 78 c8 63 6b 7e 19 28 10 f7 93 ad c0 fa 10 ce 0a 06 2d 79 52 58 9a a4 7c d5 77 1c 99 b2 cb ce 67 e8 93 d6 0e ef b9 f6 95 89 19 4e 28 ... 462 more bytes>
false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my-oh-my what excellent timing. I'm in the process of [rewriting the Node.js Cloud KMS samples](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-kms/pull/324) and lost a solid 2 hours debugging this last night. I'm going to guess this is an RSA key?

The problem is that Node discards/ignores the padding specification, resulting in a failed verification. You have to force it to use PSS padding by constructing a key object:

```
async function verify(message, signatureBuffer) {
  // Get public key
  const [publicKey] = await client.getPublicKey({
    name: 'projects/my-p/locations/.../cryptoKeyVersions/123',
  });

  // Create the verifier. The algorithm must match the algorithm of the key.
  const crypto = require('crypto');
  const verify = crypto.createVerify('sha512');
  verify.update(message);
  verify.end();

  const key = {
    key: publicKey.pem,
    padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING, // <-- THIS
  };

  const verified = verify.verify(key, signatureBuffer);
  return verified;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's an RSA key. That was it! Interesting, so it's a bug in node.js, then (crypto library)?